# Rack Error with DreamHost, Passenger, and Rails 3.0.0.rc

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, rack, bundler, dreamhost

**Background:** I have viewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354468/solve-rack-issue-for-dreamhost-and-rails-3-rc) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814856/bypassing-rack-version-error-using-rails-2-3-5) - sadly, to no avail.

**Error Message (Passenger):** You have already activated rack 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.1. Consider using bundle exec.

my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0.rc'
gem 'nifty-generators' 
gem 'nokogiri'
group :after_initialize do
    gem 'feedzirra'
end
```

my Gemfile.lock has this line:

```
rack (1.2.1)
```

my environment.rb has this line at the top:

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems') + ':/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'
```

my boot.rb has this line at the top:

```
Gem.clear_paths
```

I have rack (1.2.1) installed correctly locally - my app runs fine on my local host and version 1.2.1 shows up following a "gem list" in the terminal.

I have packaged my gems with a "bundle package" before pushing my app to my production server.

I have run the following command (on my production server, from the root of the app) before deployment:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle --local
```

Following the install command above, a "bundle check" returns this:

```
The Gemfile's dependencies are satisfied
```

And this is the backtrace provided by passenger (along with the Error Message mentioned above):

```
0   /home/user/.gems/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb      27      in `setup'
1   /home/user/.gems/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb     12  in `each'
2   /home/user/.gems/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb     12  in `each'
3   /home/user/.gems/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb  17  in `setup'
4   /home/user/.gems/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler.rb  100     in `setup'
5   /home/user/gseeds.mywebsite.com/releases/20100927012812/config/boot.rb  9   
6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
7   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
8   /home/user/gseeds.mywebsite.com/releases/20100927012812/config/application.rb   1   
9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
10  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
11  /home/user/gseeds.mywebsite.com/releases/20100927012812/config/environment.rb   7   
12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
13  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
14  config.ru   3   
15  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `instance_eval'
16  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.1.0/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `initialize'
17  config.ru   1   in `new'
18  config.ru   1
```

I'm wondering if anyone has come up with a solution to this?

Something that should be noted is that a sample rails app - aka, running a rails new appName and straight ftp'ing that to the production server on DreamHost - will run fine. This perturbs me as I imagine both my real app and the sample app have the rack (1.2.1) dependency; which implies to me that, in an effort to bypass the DreamHost server gems, I am somehow messing with rack's implementation in my real app.

I have my sample rails app running on a separate subdomain on DreamHost while getting this error for the subdomains of both the real apps I'm attempting to deploy.

Also, I originally attempted to install the gems locally in my DreamHost user directory before taking the vendor/cache approach. Maybe this doesn't affect anything..

Thanks for suffering through this messy/long question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complain to Dreamhost and tell them to upgrade Phusion Passenger. This problem has been fixed for several releases of Phusion Passenger now.

Comment: Hi Hongli, can you let us know which version of passenger fixed this? My server has 2.2.4.

Comment: Since 2.2.14 or something. I don't remember the exact version. Just upgrade to the latest version.